# Get position of regex matches in database objects using Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django app with a Postgres database that takes in user input, makes a regex based on this input, and returns the database entries that match this regex and the start and end positions of this match. The current implementation is something along the lines of:

`models.py`:

```
class SampleInputModel(models.Model):
    target_field = models.CharField()

class SampleInputModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleInputModel
        fields = '__all__'

class RecordObject(models.Model):
    record_name = models.TextField()
    record_string = models.TextField()
```

`views.py`:

```
find_regex_match(form_dict, one_record, terminating_word='keyword'):
    import re
    search_pattern = f'({form_dict['target_field']}).*(terminating_word)'
    for match in re.finditer(search_pattern, one_record.record_string):
        return '{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(
            one_record.record_name, match.start(), match.end(), 
            one_record.record_string[match.start():match.end()]
        )

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SampleInputModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form = model_to_dict(form)
            results = ''
            for one_record in RecordObject.objects.all():
                results += find_regex_match(form_dict, one_record)
            return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': results})
    else:
        form = SampleInputModelForm()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

This works and takes ~1.2 seconds on average to complete. However, I feel like there's a better way to handle the results instead of just passing a huge raw string to the template to render. I wanted to switch over to using some of the Django API for database filtering so that I can pass query sets to the templates. The new version of the code looks like:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SampleInputModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form = model_to_dict(form)

            search_pattern = f'({form_dict['target_field']}).*(terminating_word)'
            results = RecordObject.objects.filter(record_string__iregex=search_pattern)

            return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': results})
    ...
```

This query finishes super fast (< 0.005 seconds), and feels more Django-y (and I think I'll be able to format things a lot easier using a QuerySet object instead of a raw string in results.html), but I don't know how to extract the information I need from the results. I gave it a try by combining the two approaches:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SampleInputModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form = model_to_dict(form)

            search_pattern = f'({form_dict['target_field']}).*(terminating_word)'
            results = ''
            for record_match in RecordObject.objects.filter(record_string__iregex=search_pattern):
                results += find_regex_match(form_dict, record_match)

            return render(request, 'results.html', {'results': results})
    ...
```

But this is slower than the other two approaches, averaging about 3 seconds to complete. This makes sense since I'm doing the regex search (basically) twice.
Is there a better way to get the information I need after filtering the database by regex without sacrificing too much speed? Also, any general comments about the code are appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Something seems wrong with your performance measurement. If the query takes 0.005 seconds, and iterating over everything takes 1.2 seconds, then combining the query and iterating over a subset should require less than 1.2 + 0.005 seconds.

Comment: The first thing you should do is change the way you're accumulating results. Using `+=` on strings is very inefficient. Instead, collect a list of string results and then use `''.join(result_list)`.